# ssh key works on terminal but not on git

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, git, ssh-keys

I have my machine, with it's ssh key.

the public key is on the git remote machine.

I can easily connect to the Git machine with simple ssh threw terminal.

The problem is when I perform a "git pull" it still asks me for the user password although I have the key installed and works properly in simple terminal.

Any ideas?

examples:

```
.git/config  //file

[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://myUsername@git.oursite.com/var/git/lps.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


~/.ssh/config

 Host git
    HostName git.oursite.com
    User myUsername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git

 //now the ssh the works good on terminal -->
 ssh git

 //and the simple git actions that still ask for permissions
 git fetch
```

Comment: Can you please include the actual commands you ran, both for the successful and the unsuccessful case?

Comment: I don't think `git.oursite.com` is going to mtach the `git` Host. Try using `ssh://git/var/git/lps.git` instead and see if it works better.

Comment: works good! please write as an answer so I could mark it as answer.